# ERROR receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method placeOrder

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am newbie to the "WSO2 ESB" platform. I am trying to run the WSO2 ESB Rest API example from https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+800%3A+Introduction+to+REST+API, so I followed all steps

1) on one terminal, I execute

```
C:\wso2esb-4.8.1\samples\axis2Server>axis2server.bat
```

2) On another terminal

```
C:\wso2esb-4.8.1\bin>wso2esb-samples.bat -sn 800
```

and when I run the following Rest URL it gives me error. Please help me to know why last CURL command not giving the required output?

```
C:\>curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8280/stockquote/view/IBM
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8280 (#0)
> GET /stockquote/view/IBM HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8280
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 10:25:19 GMT
< Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop
e/"><soapenv:Body><ns:getQuoteResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.samples"><ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://servic
es.samples/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax21:GetQuoteResponse"><ax21:c
hange>-2.6661865959844184</ax21:change><ax21:earnings>-9.163558543387456</ax21:earnings><ax21:high>193.7355458
031858</ax21:high><ax21:last>185.33888561996295</ax21:last><ax21:lastTradeTimestamp>Sat Jul 25 15:55:19 IST 20
15</ax21:lastTradeTimestamp><ax21:low>-181.04727326807318</ax21:low><ax21:marketCap>5.0117544767788365E7</ax21
:marketCap><ax21:name>IBM Company</ax21:name><ax21:open>-183.267380995112</ax21:open><ax21:peRatio>-19.7725282
3298653</ax21:peRatio><ax21:percentageChange>-1.3311819845208677</ax21:percentageChange><ax21:prevClose>200.28
716035727143</ax21:prevClose><ax21:symbol>IBM</ax21:symbol><ax21:volume>9220</ax21:volume></ns:return></ns:get
QuoteResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

C:\>
C:\>curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8280/stockquote/view/MSFT
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8280 (#0)
> GET /stockquote/view/MSFT HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8280
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 10:27:52 GMT
< Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop
e/"><soapenv:Body><ns:getQuoteResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.samples"><ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://servic
es.samples/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax21:GetQuoteResponse"><ax21:c
hange>-2.349071151386308</ax21:change><ax21:earnings>13.743507564027315</ax21:earnings><ax21:high>-71.04465262
35375</ax21:high><ax21:last>72.46275193434585</ax21:last><ax21:lastTradeTimestamp>Sat Jul 25 15:57:52 IST 2015
</ax21:lastTradeTimestamp><ax21:low>-72.22389056575905</ax21:low><ax21:marketCap>-6410999.83409811</ax21:marke
tCap><ax21:name>MSFT Company</ax21:name><ax21:open>-71.12518655378832</ax21:open><ax21:peRatio>23.786563750758
063</ax21:peRatio><ax21:percentageChange>-2.922305475406254</ax21:percentageChange><ax21:prevClose>80.38417513
691802</ax21:prevClose><ax21:symbol>MSFT</ax21:symbol><ax21:volume>8234</ax21:volume></ns:return></ns:getQuote
Response></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

C:\>curl -v -d @placeorder.xml -H "Content-type: application/xml" http://127.0.0.1:8280/stockquote/order/
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "placeorder.xml", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8280 (#0)
> POST /stockquote/order/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8280
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/xml
> Content-Length: 0
>
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 10:28:25 GMT
< Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact**
```

server Logs:

```
15/07/25 15:53:57 INFO util.SampleAxis2ServerManager: [SimpleAxisServer] Started
Sat Jul 25 15:55:19 IST 2015 samples.services.SimpleStockQuoteService :: Generating quote for : IBM
Sat Jul 25 15:57:52 IST 2015 samples.services.SimpleStockQuoteService :: Generating quote for : MSFT
15/07/25 15:58:25 ERROR receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service
method placeOrder
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:178)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceive
r.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:1
72)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:459)

        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:279)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/07/25 15:58:25 ERROR receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred whil
e trying to invoke service method placeOrder
```

**Edit-1**: I created placeorder.xml file under /wso2esb-4.8.1 directory.

```
C:\WSO2-ESB\wso2esb-4.8.1>curl -v -d @placeorder.xml -H "Content-type: application/xml
" http://127.0.0.1:8280/stockquote/order/
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "placeorder.xml", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8280 (#0)
> POST /stockquote/order/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8280
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/xml
> Content-Length: 0
>
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 17:35:56 GMT
< Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

From the link, it seems that "The ESB returns the 202 response back to the client" . Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver: Exception occurred while
>   trying to invoke service method placeOrder
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

The above error happens when you are running the following command in your terminal.

> curl -v -d @placeorder.xml -H "Content-type: application/xml"
>   http://127.0.0.1:8280/stockquote/order/

You have to run the above curl command from the directory where you have the placeorder.xml file. Do you have placeorder.xml file in the same directory? If not, you have to either run your command from the directory where you have placeorder.xml or you have to give the path to the placeorder.xml file when you run the above curl command.

**Edit-1**
You should create the placeorder.xml file with the following content and save it in your machine.

```
<placeOrder xmlns="http://services.samples">
  <order>
     <price>50</price>
     <quantity>10</quantity>
     <symbol>IBM</symbol>
  </order>
</placeOrder>
```

Comment: You need to create this file. It won't be there in your machine by default :). I have edited my answer. Have a look at it again.

Comment: Hey, Thanks..I've updated comments below. I still see same error. But as per link "The ESB returns the 202 response back to the client", So I think its correct, but I don't understand its use 202.

Comment: Still there is a warning "Couldn't read data from file "placeorder.xml", this makes an empty POST" when you run the curl command. What content you have inside placeorder.xml? is it empty?

Comment: No, its not empty, it uses the same data that you pasted above. Wonder why its giving same error.... Regards, Neha

Comment: It could be either a permission problem (your user has no read permission over this file) or simply that the file does not exist. Also try with "--data-binary" or "--data-urlencode" instead of "-d" in your curl command.